# Gradle common repositories for multi module project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have below project setup for gradle scripts, but I would like to keep one single common repository file for both main and subprojects.
**apply from :** **"$rootDir/gradle/repositories.gradle"** does not work inside build.gradle for this purpose. It would work only if I declare repositories again inside build.gradle

```
**build.gradle**
--------------------------
{
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://myprivate.repo.com/artifactory"
            credentials {
                username = "user1"
                password = "psswd"
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        # some list of dependencies

    }
}



**gradle/repositories.gradle** 
-------------------------
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://myprivate.repo.com/artifactory"
        credentials {
            username = "user1"
            password = "psswd"
        }
    }
}


**subprojects.gradle** 
--------------------------

subprojects {
    apply from : "$rootDir/gradle/repositories.gradle"


}
```

Comment: not sure what is `subprojects.gradle` but you could add `allprojects { repositories {...})` to the  main `build.gradle` and define all repos there